# Google Plus Login with Ionic 4 and Cordova not Works

Tags: cordova, google-plus, ionic4

I´m implementing Google Login with Ionic 4. In the last project all works but now not works and give any errors. I don´t know how to fixed.

I try to downgrade to the version related to the last project when works but that makes the project fails to compile. Also tried to use my last project but when install the packages also not works.

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Stalin Maza",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "5.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "7.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
    "leaflet-gesture-handling": "^1.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "My PROJECT",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "MY_REVERSED_ID",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11.8.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "MY_APP_ID",
        "APP_NAME": "MY_APP_NAME",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "5.0.2"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

I also uses facebook login and works with any problem  but google is not working

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved using the same versión from play serviced versión due to when use different versions occurs some errors.

So I change this values

```
"cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "MY_REVERSED_ID",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11.8.0"
      },
```

To

```
"cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "11.8.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "MY_REVERSED_ID",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11.8.0"
      },
```

And delete platforms, www and plugins folder and executes the "ionic cordova build android" command and all works